# Getting instance of delegate from inside itself C#

Tags: c#, wcf, delegates

I am working with a WCF service, calls to the service are invoked using an async method. As I am working with Xamarin studio the WCF proxy must be created using the silverlight tools (slsvcutil.exe) and as such this seems to be the only way to achieve what I am doing.

To make a call to the service I must make a call like so:

```
Soap.client.DoActionCompleted += Soap_client_DoActionCompleted;
Soap.client.DoActionAsync(parameter);
```

And then declare the delegate for DoActionCompleted like so:

```
void Soap_client_DoActionCompleted(object sender, DoActionCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Soap.client.DoActionCompleted -= Soap_client_DoActionCompleted;
    // Do stuff
}
```

I have to remove Soap_client_DoActionCompleted after the call to prevent it from stacking further calls on it later.

The problem is I have many calls like this in my code, and it is beginning to get very messy and hard to follow the logic when writing the code. I would much prefer to be able to declare the code inline so it's much easier to follow, something like this:

```
Soap.client.DoActionCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    Soap.client.DoActionCompleted -= x;
    // Do stuff
}

Soap.client.DoActionAsync(parameter);
```

In the above snippet, I'd like to be able to pass the delegate that it is inside to remove it then and there, but the problem is I have no idea if this is even possible.

While I know there are almost certainly better ways of doing the above, I'm a little trapped by the fact that I am required to use slsvcutil.exe to generate the proxy for the service, and writing the proxy manually isn't an option as the service gets regular updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of possible if you assign the lambda expression to a delegate variable first.  It just won't be as nice as what you're hoping for.

And even then, to avoid a *use of unassigned local variable* compiler error, you have to first initialize the delegate variable to `null` before you can assign the lambda expression that will have a reference to itself.

So, using your example, it would look like this (I'm assuming the type of `DoActionCompleted` is `EventHandler`. Simply adjust if I'm wrong):

```
EventHandler eventHandler = null;
eventHandler = (sender, e) => 
{
    Soap.client.DoActionCompleted -= eventHandler;
    // do stuff
};
Soap.client.DoActionCompleted += eventHandler;

Soap.client.DoActionAsync(parameter);
```

It's up to you to decide if it's worth it for you to use this pattern.

Comment: Thanks sstan, your example worked perfectly. In my case, I use `EventHandler<DoActionCompletedEventArgs>` as the type. It isn't perfect but it makes it much easier to read the code in a logical order and is definitely an acceptable solution for now.

Comment: @Kizari - Don't forget to add the `@` sign in front of someone's id to make sure that they get a notification.